# Oracle SQL Developer import wizard missing?

Tags: csv, import, oracle-sqldeveloper, wizard, sqldb

I am using this tool to import a csv file to a MS sql database. I've just downloaded the free package for version 18.1.0. I am new to the tool. My research shows that if I right-click on 'Tables' I should see an option to start the import wizard; but the only option I see is 'Refresh'. I also see 'apply filter' and 'clear filter' which are greyed out. Is this because I am using a free version? Or because I am connected to a sql dbinstead of an Oracle db? My csv has 50 fields and I don't want to create my table manually e.g. thru defining an external table. Is there a practical work around for my case?

Comment: Most features work against oracle db connections.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is ONLY for an Oracle Database.

if you want support for doing things on SQL Server - you should probably be using their tools, like SSMS.

Our SQL Server support is limited to helping you get things FROM SQL Server TO Oracle.

I talk about this more [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-supports-db2-sybase-mysql-access-and-teradata/).

One exception to this is the Data Modeler. We'll let you build a relational/physical model for SQL Server, but again, the features are built for Oracle first, and sometimes only.

Comment: Your reply and link are very helpful. I wish the documentation covered it so people like me don't waste a day on this.

Comment: @Y.Eman it does - in the Concepts and Usage section of the help. Browsing objects, the features are there for Oracle tables. 3rd party database object support is limited to browsing and migrating.